# Binary search with two middle (two pointer) at same time

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

Simply I want split my array into three sub arrays not two
at first, is it logical to do this? And please help me to understand this algorithm and write it

```
def contains(elements, value):
left, right = 0, len(elements) - 1

if left <= right:
    middle = (left + right) // 2

    if elements[middle] == value:
        return True

    if elements[middle] < value:
        return contains(elements[middle + 1:], value)
    elif elements[middle] > value:
        return contains(elements[:middle], value)

return False
```

Comment: If you're splitting it into three, it's no longer a binary search by definition.  :)

Comment: Maybe you want ternary search? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search. But it seems it's really not necessary here.

Comment: Aside: that last `elif` can be changed to an `else` (`elements[middle] > value` _must_ be true at that point).

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed adapt binary search to split the array into multiple sections rather than just two. More generally, here's the idea behind k-ary search:

- Split the array into k sections of roughly equal size. (For binary search, this is two halves. For your search, that would be three thirds)
- Pick the last element of the first (k-1) sections to use as keys. (For binary search, you pick the last element of the first half, the middle element. For your search, that would be the elements at the 1/3 and 2/3 points in the array.)
- Based on how your element compares to the keys, either (1) stop searching because you found what you're looking for or (2) recursively explore the appropriate section. (In binary search, you either branch left, stop because the middle element is the one you want, or branch right. In your search, you either (1) find that your element is one of the two you picked to look at, or (2) will descend into whichever third would contain your element.)

As for whether this is a good idea - this very well may be a good idea! In a k-ary search, you keep shrinking the array by a factor of k at each iteration, so there will be roughly log<sub>k</sub> n = (log n) / (log k) iterations of the algorithm. Each iteration looks at k - 1 keys, so you're doing O(k) work. This means that the work done is O((k / log k) n). The quantity k / log k is minimized when you pick k = e (that is, about 2.7182828), so picking k = 2 or k = 3 are good choices. However, because of how processor caches work, I suspect that picking k = 2 would be faster overall because there would be fewer cache misses. (And hey! We tend to use binary search in practice, so this is probably not a bad idea.)

Interestingly, the [B-tree data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), which is used extensively in databases, uses something similar to this to store its elements. Due to how B-trees are structured, B-trees typically pick k to be some huge number, but in a regular array search this probably wouldn't be a good idea.

Hope this helps!